# Tableau Finding count of two classificatory varibles

Tags: count, tableau-api

I am new to tableau 10.  I have two class variables say A and B entered in rows at the top of my worksheet. What I want is the count of A and B (in statistics we call A*B an interaction). I want the number of rows with A and B attributes.

Thanks.
Mary A Marion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with the help of [Sets](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_sets.html) in Tableau or using a Filter. I will explain the procedure for both with this sample dataset.

```
+--------+--------+------+
| ClassA | ClassB | Name |
+--------+--------+------+
|      1 |      1 | Abc  |
|      0 |      0 | Def  |
|      0 |      1 | Ghi  |
|      0 |      1 | Jkl  |
|      0 |      1 | Mno  |
|      1 |      0 | Pqr  |
|      1 |      0 | Stu  |
|      1 |      0 | Vwx  |
|      1 |      1 | yz   |
+--------+--------+------+
```

**Set** - We create a set from name the 'Name' field as shown below

[image]

We should create the set based on a condition. When ClassA = 1 AND ClassB = 1. We do that as shown below. I am naming the set with the default name 'Set 1'

[image]

Now, drag 'Set 1' and 'Number of Records' to the rows. We would get something as shown below.

[image]

This can be read as 2 member are in the set, while 7 do not satisfy the condition and are out of the set.

**Filter** - Add ClassA and ClassB to the filter and select the values you want to see. Below is the screenshot of the output of adding a filter

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this answer was useful you can upvote it, and if it answers your question satisfactorily please do hit the check-mark to accept it as the solution.

Comment: I am fine with what you did until the last step. I can read off the number of rows that satisfy a condition but I am not getting the screenshots of the output of adding a filter to match what you have.There are 4 sets in this problem. I would like to place the output of each additional set to the right of the previous sets output. When I attempt to follow your procedure with multiple sets the output is confusing. So what I am doing is finding the number of records for each set and putting the results for each set  in a different worksheet. This is not as efficient as I would like it to be?

Comment: I have the four worksheets in one dashboard. Each worksheet fills the width of its portion of the page. So still not quite right but 4 graphs are on one page now. Thanks!